# tinyMCE disable Undo/Redo function

Tags: tinymce

I need to disable Undo/Redo function in tinyMCE. I saw the documentantion and I used this functions:

```
ed.onUndo.add(function(ed, e) {
                tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
ed.onRedo.add(function(ed, e) {
                tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
```

but without any success. 
Note: ed is my active editor.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using tinyMCE 4.*, you can disable Undo/Redo by returning *false* on *[BeforeAddUndo](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.BeforeAddUndo)* event:

```
ed.on('BeforeAddUndo', function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE v4 - Just overwrite the default settings.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#content',
  toolbar: 'bold italic strikethrough underline | quicklink | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link ',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, but the solution is a bit hacky.
There is ajavascript class in the tinymce core that we needed to overwrite: `tinymce.UndoManager`.

We used a variable sticked to the editor object to decide if the creation of an undo step actually should take place or not: `tinymce.activeEditor.disable_undo_creation`.
Here is the code part of the overwritten class:

```
        add : function(level) {

            if (tinymce.activeEditor.disable_undo_creation) return;

            var i, settings = editor.settings, lastLevel;

            level = level || {};
            level.content = getContent();

            // Add undo level if needed
            lastLevel = data[index];
            if (lastLevel && lastLevel.content == level.content)
                return null;

            // Time to compress
            if (settings.custom_undo_redo_levels) {
                if (data.length > settings.custom_undo_redo_levels) {
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++)
                        data[i] = data[i + 1];

                    data.length--;
                    index = data.length;
                }
            }

            // Get a non intrusive normalized bookmark
            level.bookmark = editor.selection.getBookmark(2, true);

            // Crop array if needed
            if (index < data.length - 1)
                data.length = index + 1;

            data.push(level);
            index = data.length - 1;

            self.onAdd.dispatch(self, level);
            editor.isNotDirty = 0;

            return level;
        },
```

When the editor is unable to create undo steps redo/undo won't work anymore.

Comment: I will try this when i get back at home!